# JQuery show / hide not working IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

Show / hide does not work IE7. 
In the other browsers work fine.
Help me please.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
<div id="secondary_nav" class="box">                    
    <ul>    
        <li><a href="">test</a></li>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="height: 336px; display: none;">
            <li><a href="">test</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </ul>                
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#secondary_nav ul li").hover(function() {
            $(this).next(".sub-menu").show();
            $(this).next(".sub-menu").hover(function() {
                    $(this).show();
                }, function() {$(this).hide();}
            );
        },function() {$(this).next(".sub-menu").hide();}
    );
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Put your inner UL inside a LI and it will work!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to fix your markup. A sub-menu goes in the the same `li` as the link that represents it:

```
<div id="secondary_nav" class="box">                    
  <ul>    
    <li>
      <a href="">test</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu" style="height: 336px; display: none;">
        <li><a href="">test</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>                
</div>
```

Next you have some issues with your `$.hover()` where you're performing an additional nested hover within the over state of the first. Let's clean that up as well:

```
$(function(){
  $("#secondary_nav > ul > li").hover(
    function(){ $(".sub-menu", this).show(); },
    function(){ $(".sub-menu", this).hide(); }
  );
});
```

​Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4KFac/

Comment: No, you need to work it in the markup that I originally wrote.

Comment: @user1404412 No, you need to write proper markup. You cannot write malformed HTML and then be disappointed when the browser doesn't behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code is broken. You can't have an `ul` tag directly inside another `ul` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/Ln8ep/1/
Try to use `$(document).ready(function() {`